# Prompts from LUIS model in multi turn bot

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS model with required Action Parameters. When trying to form a query and a required parameter is not detected by luis it sets triggered to false and asks a relevant question as a prompt.

I would like to use this prompt when developing a multi turn dialog using bot framework. In the basic multi turn example in botframework(v3) sdk when the entity is not detected then it prompts for a question using local prompts module.

I already have prompts in luis and I am wondering if there is anyway to use those ?

My intent is correctly recognized but my query deliberately misses specifying the entity. A query like this when trying in luis correctly shows prompt in response but I do not see args being passed to my callback upon intent detection to have any prompts.